# Sending 2d C++ vector in MPI

Tags: mpi, stdvector

Is there a simple way to send a 2d vector in C++, say `vector<vector<int>> A(size,vector<int>(size))` from one node to another using MPI? If not, what would be the least complicated way to do this? Would it be easier to send a 2d array rather than a 2d std::vector ?